# Arrays "expected constant expression" and "unrecognized dimension"

Tags: arrays

I'm using Visual Studio and in the main.c I have **two errors** (I reported them in the commented lines in the code). I don't understand what the problem is.

```
  int main(void)
    {
            int32_t nItem1 = 0, nItem2 = 0; //the errors persist even if HERE I declare "int32_t 
                                            // nItem1 = 5" or "int32_t nItem1"
        printf("Enter no of elements of Array-1 and Array-2:");
        scanf("%d %d", &nItem1, &nItem2);

    if ((nItem1 < 0) || (nItem2 < 0))
    {
        printf("Number of elements cannot be negative\n");
        wait_for_user_input();
        return 0;
    }

    int32_t array1[nItem1];  //ERRORS: "expected constant expression" and "unrecognized dimension"
    int32_t array2[nItem2];  //ERRORS: "expected constant expression" and "unrecognized dimension"


for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nItem1; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter %d element of array1:", i);
        scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
    }

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nItem2; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter %d element of array2:", i);
        scanf("%d", &array2[i]);
    }
    }
```